# Server Side Validation Show Success or Error message inline

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I built a form for my class (private access only) where every one submit a form with some information. The information like Full name of the course, Subject, Select options for the list of teachers and a checkboxes for available class rooms. Some might like big or small rooms and available accessories for study. I did an effort for designing and built a form in bootstrap and php. Forms looks Okay and the validation is inline till I need to include one more feature in it. Every time when i submit a form it gets loaded. I mean, the form works with the php and html validation but the whole page gets loaded everytime i click the submit. I google it and know the this goal should be achieve by Ajax. I watched youtube videos and follow other questions here but got nothing. Inline validation or show the success message on the same page still not working. I want is when the user submit the form it will show the alert-success message on the samepage without refreshing or the error message inline if any errors there with server side validation. Codes easily available on internet.

html:

```
<?php 
    include('ajaxreturn.php');
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <body>


         <form id="submit" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
              <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group">
              <label class="form-control-label" for="Name">Name</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" name="name" value= "<?php if (isset($_POST["name"])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]) ?>">
              <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $name_error;?></span>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
              <label class="form-control-label" for="subject">Subject</label>
              <input class="form-control form-control" type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value= "<?php if (isset($_POST["subject"])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["subject"]) ?>">
              <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $subject_error;?></span>
                  </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Category">Category</label>
                  <select class="form-control pt-0 pb-0" id="category">
                    <option>...</option>
                    ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
                <div class="form-check pl-3 pt-1">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input name="classroom" id="classroom" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" <?php if (isset($classroom) && $classroom=="classroom") echo "checked";?> value="classroom">
                    L-1
                  </label>
                </div>
                <span class="text-danger pl-3 pt-0"><?php echo $classroom_error;?></span>

                </div> 
                div class="row">
                <div class="form-check pl-3 pt-1">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input name="classroom" id="classroom" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" <?php if (isset($classroom) && $classroom=="classroom") echo "checked";?> value="classroom">
                    L-2
                  </label>
                </div>
                <span class="text-danger pl-3 pt-0"><?php echo $classrooms_error;?></span>

                </div> 
          <div class="row">
            <button id="submit" name="submit" value="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">submit</button>
<span class="text-danger"> Wrong!</span>
<span class="text-success"> Thanks!</span>
          </div>
          </form>


        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- <script src="main.js"></script> -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

php:

```
<?php

// Form Variables 
$name = "";
$subject = "";
$category = "";
$classroom="";

//Error Variables
$name_error ="";
$subject_error = "";
$category_error = "";
$classroom_error = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $name_error = "Your Name";
  } else {
    $name = validation($_POST["name"]);
    // Function calling and checking the letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $name_error = "Your name must contain Letters, Numbers and Spaces"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
    $subject_error = "Your Subject";
  } else {
    $website = validation($_POST["subject"]);
    // Function calling and checking the letters and whitespace
    if ((!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$]/", $subject)) {
      $subject_error = "Subjets must contain Letters, Numbers and Spaces";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["category"])) {
    $category_error = "Please select categoy";
  } else {
    $category = validation($_POST["category"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["classroom"])) {
    $classroom_error = "Select the Class Room";
  } else {
    $classroom = validation($_POST["classroom"]);
  }
}




function validation($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

?>
```

Ajax:

```
<script>
  function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
  function submitForm(){
  _("submit").disabled = true;
  _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append( "name", _("name").value );
  formdata.append( "subject", _("subject").value );
  formdata.append( "category", _("category").value );
  formdata.append( "classroom", _("classroom").value );
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open( "POST", "ajaxreturn.php" );
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
      if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
        _("submit").innerHTML = '<h2>Thanks '+_("name").value+', your message has been sent.</h2>';
      } else {
        _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        _("submit").disabled = false;
      }
    }
  }
  ajax.send( formdata );
}
</script>
```

Error:

```
ajaxform.php?name=&website=&submit=submit:78 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at submitForm (ajaxform.php?name=&website=&submit=submit:78)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (ajaxform.php?name=&website=&submit=submit:58)
submitForm @ ajaxform.php?name=&website=&submit=submit:78
onclick @ ajaxform.php?name=&website=&submit=submit:58

ajaxform.php?name=&website=&submit=submit:78 
formdata.append( "category", _("category").value );

onclick @ ajaxform.php?name=&website=&submit=submit:58
        <button name="submit" id="submit" onclick="submitForm()" value="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">submit</button>
```

Category with Select options Tag

```
   <option value=1>1</option>
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=1>1</option><option value=1>1</option>
```

Comment: Its not reading the category value, your <label for="Category"> is capitalized, not sure if that interferes with your php. You still have the type="submit" take that off (on your button). Thats what submits your form, you want only the function to happen, not the form to be submitted via the form POST. Look at my example

Comment: should i define each category with <options> tag. I include category from php server side. i mean classrooms can be change it wont be hardcoded in html.

Comment: Take the type="submit" off of your button.

Comment: same error when define each category in html ..

Comment: It looks like the same exact error, did you not edit properly?

Comment: Edit Question again with <options tag i put as an example

Comment: this is more readable

Comment: You need "1" around the 1 I believe. did you fix your button? and remove the type="submit"? At this point remove the category and see if it works.

Comment: php reads by the name attr, removed type and value. still same thing

Comment: that is just an example for the options tag i put in html.. it was like <option value = 1>1</option><option value=2>2</option>..........

Comment: my category select tags <select name="category" class="form-control pt-0 pb-0" id="category ControlSelect1">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying changing the ajax inside to this.

```
if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
   this.responseText;
```

The rest of your code above looks right. I have never seen xmlhttprequest used having a variable name inside, Usually it looks like

```
var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr1.open('POST', "ajaxreturn.php", true);
xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        dostuff = this.responseText;
  };//end onreadystate
 xhr1.send();
```

I dont know enough php to take a look at your server side validation. I use NodeJs for all of that. Did you console log your this.responseText to see what variable your server is sending back. Also don't have your submit button submit, that is also your problem, have it run the onSubmit function. So...

```
<button id="submit" name="submit" onclick="submitForm()" class="btn btn-success">submit</button>
```

and take the onSubmit off of your form tag. I believe this will fix your issues.

When you submit the form, thats what opens a new page, when you just run the function with ajax, that won't make the browser open a new page. It just happens in the background.

Comment: No its not working same thing.. i tried with Onsubmit with off form tag also tried other variables u just defined up, same thing before .. Anyway Thanks for this .

Comment: What does the console log say for this.responseText?

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: OnSubmit is not ajaxform.php " Actually its shows for a second and gone. I tried to read it by hitting submit button many times but this is the best i can read for less then a second. Also it just say Thanks! that was my status <p><span> Thanks</span></p>

Comment: It needs to be the function submitForm() attached to the button, as that is the function you are defining in your script. And then it should work, it was referencing an unknown function.

Comment: I edit my question to show you the error and error lines.

Comment: It is the same error you said about the categories. And the onSubmit being undefined. All you have to do is remove the onSubmit and see my example and place the proper button code there, (REMOVE type="Submit") and then on the php side add the new object of categories to the code, you will receive it back in the response from php so you DONT even need it in your HTML or JS. Those are your two errors, if you follow this it will work fine.

Comment: you are right. No errors now but also no errors from server side. Now if i submit my form it with blank it shows nothing.
The ajax code in example like this now: 
xhr1.open('POST', "ajaxreturn.php", true);
   xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
     if(this.responseText == "success"){
      console.log(this.responseText);
      _("submiturl").innerHTML = '<h2>Thanks '+_("name").value+', your message has been sent.</h2>';
     } else {
      _("status").innerHTML = xhr1.responseText;
      _("submit").disabled = false;

Comment: What does the console log say of responsetext? You have to actually send back a string that says "success" for that if statement to happen.You are sending back $data, remove the if statement and your code will work fine. Its blank because you aren't doing anything with the response.

Comment: now console is empty. It means no error and its not getting the object from php. Now what i am getting here is if i write a php code that also passes the php errors inside the lines and also shows the success message on the page then it would works fine. I just write a code for php and also added jsut few extra lines in ajax that passes the error data from php. Let me know if i get it ?
 $data is only the function for validations the variables inside php(only in server). It doesn't link with html. Only $errors and the data getting from name attr from html link with the html.

Comment: I have done it :) .. Thanks for following me all the way to here

Comment: I am glad to help, it was sure an adventure haha. go build some cool stuff, I would recommend you learn NodeJs and ditch the php, soooo much easier. And you use javascript on the front end and backend.

Comment: haha it was a very small mistake. I used two versions of jquery both in a same file. The code woks when i remove slim version of jquery. 
Node.js I sure do ..